# What's a good way to take multiple parallel subsets of a data frame in R?

Tags: r

Consider this simple data frame:

```
test <- data.frame(v1=c(7,3,1,5,9,0,2),v2=c("A","C","E","C","B","K","F"))
```

[image]

I can easily take the subset where v1>3 or the subset where v1>5, but how do I get both at the same time?

The code

```
test[test$v1>3,]
```

produces

[image],

while

```
test[test$v1>5,]
```

produces

[image].

I was hoping this code

```
test[test$v1>c(3,5),]
```

would create a list where each item is one of the subsets.

[image]

But R is trying to compare the two vectors element-by-element.  So it only produces the latter subset along with this error statement.

[image]

Suggestions?

Comment: The key word is `or`: `test[test$v1 > 3 or test$v1 > 5,]`

Comment: In general, I actually have a very long list of subsetting conditions I need to apply.  So I need to be able to express the conditions as some kind of "outer" of two vectors.  I tried expressing the condition as outer(test$v1,c(3,5),">"), but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lapply` is designed to do this kind of operators:

```
lapply(c(15, 20), function(x) mtcars[mtcars$mpg > x,])
```

For each number in the vector, it subsets the dataset with that number and `lapply` returns a list of those subsets.

**Result:**

```
[[1]]
                   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Merc 240D         24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280          19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Merc 280C         17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
Merc 450SE        16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SL        17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SLC       15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Fiat 128          32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic       30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla    33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corona     21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Dodge Challenger  15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
AMC Javelin       15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
Pontiac Firebird  19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
Fiat X1-9         27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2     26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa      30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
Ford Pantera L    15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
Ferrari Dino      19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
Volvo 142E        21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2

[[2]]
                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
Volvo 142E     21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.  This is equivalent to just the subset on the first condition.  I need a list of subsets.  In both your example and in mine, the second subset would be smaller than the first (since the second condition is more restrictive).  But, in general, I need to be able to produce a list that may contain thousands of different subsets.

Comment: @Jay I see that I have misinterpreted your question. In this case, a simple `lapply` would suffice. See my update

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for.  Thank you, @useR

Answer (score 0):

A possible option with `tidyverse` would be

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(c(3, 5), ~ test %>%
                  filter(v1 > .x))
#[[1]]
#  v1 v2
#1  7  A
#2  5  C
#3  9  B

#[[2]]
#  v1 v2
#1  7  A
#2  9  B
```